# Molesto error 419

Tags: laravel

En algunas ocasiones aleatorias me aparece el molesto error 419, pero principalmente mis usuarios reportan este error al hacer login o almacenar un formulario.

Ya tengo puesto todos los tokens csrf en todos los formularios y borre el campo SESSION_DOMAIN de mi archivo .env

Realmente me gustaría saber si hay algo mas que pudiera hacer para solventar este error ya que he intentando todo lo que he encontrado y no veo salida.

Este es el código de mi login.

```
<form method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="logo-login">
                <img src="/adminlte/dist/img/aunclicklogo.png" alt="Aunclick logo" >
                
            </div>

            @if (session('errors'))

                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h5><i class="fas fa-times"></i> {{session('errors')->first('error')}}</h5>
                </div>

            @endif

            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-43">
                Inicio de sesión
            </span>
            
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                <input class="input100 @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Correo" id="email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                {{-- <span class="label-input100">Correo</span> --}}

                @error('email')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
                    
                    
            <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="input100 @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                {{-- <span class="label-input100">Contraseña</span> --}}
                @error('password')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
```

Comment: El error mismo sucede porque "falta el token csrf". Esto pasa porque no se incluye en los formularios el `csrf` o "expiro la sesion". Tal vez esto ultimo te este pasando por lo que veo

Comment: @JuanRivera si te fijas en mi codigo veras el token justo en el formulario

Comment: Por eso digo en la parte final de mi comentario que tu problema puede deberse a que expira la sesion, pero tendrias que comprobarlo tu mismo ya que en tu pregunta pones "*principalmente mis usuarios reportan este error al hacer login o almacenar un formulario*"

Comment: @JuanRivera si, pero al hacer login se supone que la sesión no estaba abierta, sino mas bien deberia abrirse. En dado caso que la sesion expire, tengo programado que se redireccione al login nuevamente.